# How to solve this optimization question with the Extreme Value Theorem?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

Consider the region in the x-y plane that is bounded by the x-axis and the function $f(x)=b-ax^2$. Construct a rectangle whose base lies on the x-axis and is centered at the origin, and whose sides extend vertically until they intersect the curve $f(x)=b-ax^2$. Which has the greatest combined perimeter and area? (a and b are positive parameters).

So far, I've got that 0 ≤ x ≤ ${\sqrt (\frac ba)}$, and the combined area and perimeter when x = 0 is 2b whereas it is $4{\sqrt (\frac ba)}$ when x = ${\sqrt (\frac ba)}$. Now I have problem finding the critical value of the function which describes the combination of area and perimeter.

Comment: @Christian Blatter Thank you; because we haven't studied determinant yet, is there any easier way to prove that the rectangle with "the greatest combined area and perimeter" do not exist? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is a basic experience (and a great problem for mankind) that you cannot optimize with respect to two objective functions at the same time. So there is   no such thing as a rectangle  with "greatest combined area and perimeter".

Given two such objective functions you have to weigh them somehow against each other, in other words: to define the trade-off between the two.

Comment: I understand. That's what I'm looking for: under what circumstances, there could be the optimization given two parameters a and b.